# How to run a script on entry form before saving data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi I have created an entry form. On the form, there are a field called 'ordernum' I have created a script that gets the last id from order table and ad 1 on the result. When user click on submit buton I want the script to insert the number in 'ordernum'field on the form before sending data to the action page for insertion to db.

The scrip is working well I just dont know how to make it work before data insertion.

the script is:

```
    <script>

    function updateorder(){
$.post('../subs/name2.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
    $('#ordernum').val(data);
    });
     };

    </script>

    I did this on my form
    <form action="../subs/custompcorder.php/" method="post" id="form"  onsubmit="updateorder()">
    <input id="order" type="text" name="ordernumt"/> 
     </form>
```

Comment: the purpose of using the submit buton to update the field is to make sure user wants to save and also make sure to grab the last id in case of many people using the form at the same time

Comment: how does this script work well? you don't even have a submit button so how will `onsubmit` fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad practice.  Your PHP side knows the next ID to be used in the insert; why not just grab it as a part of the form processing code rather than retrieving it as a separate request and then submitting *that* number back to the PHP side?  The "next insert ID" is *never* something that javascript needs to handle for you.

Further, consider the scenario where your code *is* being used by many people at a time:

1. users a,b,c fill out form and press submit.
2. post requests fire off
3. post requests each simultaneously notice id 10 is the nextavailable ID
4. post requests all return 10
5. each form is updated to hold 10 and submitted
6. id 10 is inserted 3 times to the database depending on your db schema, either all of them get inserted with the same ID, or the first one gets inserted and the next 2 fail on a duplicate key.

You never want to request the next ID for a row from a table, and then insert into it.  Eventually you'll end up requesting the same ID twice and then trying to insert it twice.

This is precisely why AUTO_INCREMENT exists for database tables.  Let your *database* handle your data, and then use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` to pull the ID you inserted into your application *after* insert.

Comment: Thank you Dan for this well elaborated answer. You are perfectly right about id dupliction in case of simultanious insert. in my case, I am filling up the oder and order_details table. Order table has the order number as AUTO_INCREMENT how do I use how and where should I use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); to insert the next order ID in order_details table. The reason I went so far is because I don't know how to use the next ID. Thank you again

Comment: I forgot to mention that last order ID should be added to each item for same order in the order_details.

Comment: The ideal case would be to use a mysql transaction to make sure both tables were updated, or neither.  But that's beyond what you're asking.  The most likely process in your scenario would be to run the `INSERT INTO orders...`, then pull the last insert id back into PHP.  From there you can do the `INSERT INTO order_details...` and any other tables in which you track the order.

Answer (score 0):

My insert form looks like this: many rows are created for the same order number. order_id, order_id1, order_id2.... should be the same next id from order form.

```
  <?php
include '../db/connect.php';


$sql="INSERT INTO oz2ts_custompc_details (part_id, quantity, price, status_id,order_id)
VALUES
```

('$_POST[part_id]','$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[status_id]','$_POST[order_id]'),
('$_POST[part_id2]','$_POST[quantity2]','$_POST[price2]','$_POST[status_id2]','$_POST[order_id2]'),
('$_POST[part_id3]','$_POST[quantity3]','$_POST[price3]','$_POST[status_id3]','$_POST[order_id3]')";

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO oz2ts_custompc (platform)
VALUES
('$_POST[platform]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "record(s) added";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also put it this way
and I will like to just get the last inserted order numer after insert on order table
and use it in order_id in place of $_POST[order_id] $_POST[order_id2] and $_POST[order_id3]

```
   <?php
  include '../db/connect.php';


 $sql="INSERT INTO oz2ts_custompc (platform)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[platform]')";


 $sql1="INSERT INTO oz2ts_custompc_details (part_id, quantity, price,   status_id,order_id)
 VALUES
```

('$_POST[part_id]','$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[status_id]','$_POST[order_id]    '),     ('$_POST[part_id2]','$_POST[quantity2]','$_POST[price2]','$_POST[status_id2]','$_POST[order    _id2]'),     ('$_POST[part_id3]','$_POST[quantity3]','$_POST[price3]','$_POST[status_id3]','$_POST[order    _id3]')";

```
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
 {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 echo "record(s) added";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advices. It was simple but too hard for beginner like me.
Here is how it has been done:

```
<?php
include '../db/connect.php';


$sql="INSERT INTO oz2ts_custompc (platform)
VALUES
('intel')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))

{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$orderid=mysqli_insert_id($con);
echo $orderid;


$sql1="INSERT INTO oz2ts_custompc_details (part_id, quantity, price,    status_id,order_id)
VALUES
('$_POST[part_id]','$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[status_id]','$orderid'),
  ('$_POST[part_id2]','$_POST[quantity2]','$_POST[price2]','$_POST[status_id2]','$orderid'),
```

('$_POST[part_id3]','$_POST[quantity3]','$_POST[price3]','$_POST[status_id3]','$orderid')";

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "record(s) added";

?>
```